# python django media_root

Tags: python, django

If I use the code below it will find my base.css under the project folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}/media/a/admin/css/base.css{% endblock %}" />

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/a/'
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

However, if I use the code below, it will go to the `\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\media\css` to find base.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}/a/admin/css/base.css{% endblock %}" />

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/a/'
(r'^a/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Does anyone know the reason why this happens?

Thanks~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake:

i haven't set the  "runsever --adminmedia" command

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have your ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/a/admin/'

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix

> Make sure to use a trailing slash, and
>   to have this be different from the
>   MEDIA_URL setting (since the same URL
>   cannot be mapped onto two different
>   sets of files).